# Proving or disproving a limit of a complex-valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, epsilon-delta

**Prove** or **Disprove** $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} z \sin \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) = 0$.

**My Approach:** Since this result is true for real variable $z=x$, and since the real line contains the accumulation points of $\mathbb{C}$, by the **Identity Principle**  the assertion holds for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ as well.

I want to see without using the "Identity Principle", how to establish the limit. Any appropriate suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False:
Let $z=ia$ ($a$ real) then $sin({\frac{1}{z})=\frac{e^{1/a}-e^{-1/a}}{2i}}$ So $ae^{1/a}\to \infty$ for $a\to 0+$ while $ae^{-1/a}\to \infty$ for $a\to 0-$

Comment: So why isn't this follow from the "Identity Principle" ?

Comment: I am not familiar with the "Identity Principle", so I can't comment on it.  However as you see the assertion is false.  From what I gathered (Wikipedia) the function has to be analytic, which is obviously not at $z=0$.